# Leaflet converting MultiLineString to a Polygon

Tags: polyline-creation

I have created a polyline encoding for the Ganges River. When I display this in Leaflet, it gives me a connecting line (meaning it is converting the Line into a polygon). How do I get rid of this red line.

PS - It shows correctly in "geojson.io (load encoded polyline)", and also works correctly in "Google Static Map API" (both screenshots attached).

Here is my leaflet code. I am using the "Polyline.encoded.js" library from Jieter (https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.encoded)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Leaflet L.Polyline.fromEncoded()</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 400px"></div>

    <script src="Polyline.encoded.js"></script>
    <script>
        var map = new L.Map('map');
        L.tileLayer(
            'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>',
                maxZoom: 18
            }
        ).addTo(map);

        var encoded = 'c|o{Dm{hfNjeEl~BvfBdh@p_Cn@dgBg^lsEgeB`qBsc@jd@`Bj%5CnMxd@bEb}@uVvy@kt@ruA{yB`gAkd@bZlqBjy@nz@niDlqA`dAlw@~`AblBxw@rcA`iCxiBppHn~CjkCz_BpbBlnCjq@||DoHf|DooAdoC{`FpnFadBhxCuf@tmCrx@vpC~|Nz{OnmGjeDngBb_CxlArkH~hA`yBnaDbr@vD?p|Ctf@fmC|bBbtBhhC`vCxwHlRltAmBz_ByZngAki@xl@ag@n]uTjTka@t}C}SjxUfI`yBxmFv|QlRl~Cnb@zyBpoCbzI`OvvAw%5Cvy@`Jtv@nXzr@nM`o@_OboAm_ArgEyGltAhYnw@`}EluGjqJbmHdoCngAjxCrVnyCom@{ZtqHbEbu@xRfeA|@dpIqPz_Agc@jdAyw@vv@gdEzbAu~@xiB}Hd_Czj@hkBeh@~x@cb@xlAiQdrAdHnjAlrGrtErzCrc@nlBfxA~wD~yEbqMp_LrwCdx@l~CcHhmCoZhoOkxDttGqm@lbG|u@|dErtEd_ChiHjq@xlAdX~[vGbb@Vp}Axd@diD~`BtpCniCjnBj{Cr`A~~FkGroEixBj}DswCpiEghBl|AsFb~DjTv~AwLt~@g{@jq@upA`dAui@~uBf{@neHqaEjhDmtAlqBaBf`A|XnbAcHz_AuVhy@}KnlAbb@heD`fDdmAdu@bcOrVldAkTnzIpm@thCiAhoEclCrjCucAxdBvLn_Ahn@vy@fA~{@wObgAmJz]rFvy@`_@de@rFbm@{RbZgk@zPwl@pPuY|XeXvDoZ`J{Uti@}Hp]lGjiAp`@zUpC|e@iQtq@ao@pe@aR|bB{b@nz@{e@xvBqwBjcDaiBrbCiDhhC`b@nvDdK|xHowBf|NkpLbeH_yAnj@|h@dh@n]bj@xO~FoMh^o]xj@q]`l@uLl_AzUvy@fk@lw@lZfx@_%5Cdp@mj@v~@ka@|eAcUxdAkGv~AuYnbAkaAfuBoaD`~CgrBdu@{r@drAs}Bxo@uv@h_FgrCr|EwzElvCqzAd_Cwl@fpAmtAhiHcaL|`@inA|K{oAp]s}AlgAkaAntA}u@tfAi~@be@}eAtxAuqGph@efGlWmw@fpA}oBlg@wcCpXs~GnwBa{Lnw@{oBp|D}sG`_Amg@`sCw%5Cd`Aee@jfAqwCs[waI`_AeoCzb@k~BkiAooIzz@u}C|m@sc@hn@_Ovt@mJf`AkTrkHwsCdhAaOzoA?fhAcH~p@eh@lvCaaKblBglE`oAqqEdP{cFemAsaG|vFioEl~BodChv@ucBtYylAbtBelCtYcoAbMcoBph@{r@vaAaRtqGmW`gA_%5CtkA_|@lyAsjCnbAqmA~}B_fAplCsV|kGwLfcAyRz_A_%5C~uBknApyEg|E~}@ab@rzCyo@~eBiuBlqC}pHfvGcmIfhAguB|XcoAfFwi@hA_l@iv@mbH~[wsBnyCk~BtpL}vFhmC}oB~{@}XvaAtIdbAbU|}@|K`|AuYhsAs`AzwJctL~oCeoBz|C_l@nuGyOvkCcXdwBmg@pzB}rArzBgbC~}AgrChfAoxGvvA_vA|zBiq@lhEwv@ztJwpDndCuf@nm@uv@lWojAfFcoAvd@ab@`{Doj@zgAg[pcHczIr`@wfAjWufAl_IkjOtcB}bB~bB_i@lxO}_CtcA_BxtAi^bb@ghAbUeuAhn@kaArcA_%5Czr@`Bvq@vOf`AdHxw@yOja@mj@`w@{lB`zGe}Hd}@ikBlEa_Awd@}oBaJoz@dHqzA|Xgk@lg@cb@fs@w|@~`AeoCjl@}r@zoAiT|eAnMpu@nPhf@qS`Z}_BupBerBa_AebC_%5CswC{EoqDyOixBy_Ay`FJwpCta@m~Cz_AciCthB{_Bn|Csc@~rBucAldB{|CrhAujDx_@{lBpXelD`o@iuC|bBghBz_Ja|@fxAkaAbr@qwB~}Aq{HlZin@ltI_aJd`@cr@zUqjBh^}u@vqAy|@vy@vLzw@jt@`lAvy@vsCrc@ziCce@~eBsjBvaAi_GntBeoChYqzApCstEfNwLhYaB~}Aq`Azz@q]du@qp@`g@a|AdCalAcj@okEbZibE~kAex@hxBcUh}CqzAh^}e@~[spAdXwl@|bC}_CzEikAuLgoDd[cbAdrAkkCyOm~BgeCilGcbAsqGrF{iCvqAoz@bdClZbtBlt@b|B`b@x~CuYbcFmaBveE}rBbbA{oA~x@ayBbUodCoe@}oBcr@ucB}@clBxg@yiBxlAs}AxaBgk@rpAo@hv@sc@rSiuCag@ogBgoDm{Dag@ciCzJa_Ar^qmAhn@s`Avy@g[tkAtIvq@zUbm@p]`|@bX|aF|u@|bB?noAab@|e@qzAsK{|Bqp@{cFy|@|u@s{@t}Cgk@ltAoyBgrB_nBi~@{oAgkA{]kxCxlAyfCfkHk~AtDwcCcbAufAsoDyiA}u@cbAfFowAbr@ghBxdAwcB`_AeeApxG_}ExdBk{Bz_Ae|DhIqtC_TciDwiAwyA{uGb|Ckl@mqBhDavD`WyfCteDcjHvjF_zGv`E}mHtf@gcJisBg|EseJ_tH{jAkbG`JcsE{b@ylAyiBogAyqBy_@odBlJgxAvi@qmA`_AkrEm{E}SmgQszCkbFakDss@mcEdKw`Dh{AebAbvDe`@bbAkiAom@_~BoqCs`Aao@kxCknAq}@}eAyb@sgDp`AmaCn|AszBjiA}iFbtBoaCtYowAuQucB}rAycDkTqzA`o@wcDrzB}iDdsGk_HtcByvCh^umCi{@euAimD~NwtH`mFonDfkAmlAowB__@ibDmqAkkCqaFy}FmtAclBif@_iBqm@o{DeS_sD`g@knAnj@ia@jg@yiAhs@wiA|mAq`@`nC_%5CjqAuYzr@}XhkAerBvGafCoe@s~G?{`GeKihBwa@eh@wt@}XydAoz@gyFwnKguBieCixKytIseKgtOu{@kbFxnBwmEvyAg[rrBaRhvAoz@xGwsCyqAwsBu|Gy}Ey|@{oB}XusAgp@odBq[ogBlb@a|AhrD{cEbjAguBji@oaD~s@maBdPui@hIikA}Po_KdKihB~h@wsBcw@geC{Uc}HqeAw`Cm~Bk~BojAyvB{Uu`Cb]w`Dx`FofNb]goDkWoqCqoButG}`@cyCJkkCji@seKxj@khDvkBucB`uGihCjkBotBbUszBdC{|BhfAkhDrh@wsCjGkT~[ao@r`A_l@drB_y@|jBeeA~pAwiAnr@c|AhQs}B|`@mtAdtC{`F|`@usBeu@ioEu`CuwE}cHooJr}JevGd}AihBlcD_wGfcA{oA`o@smBsc@guByxEk|Hyg@ebBkWerBsFumCzbAgcI`fDsaG|wKsoM|iE{zHjcC{iCp|Cex@bU}bA}HiyH`JqzA_G_iAd`@c`H~c@guAbE_|@i~@sdF_DwsBd]qgBxo@}eBzbAebBvvAebBb@yiAwnBatJe_CugFw`Ey`Ei_FavCs|EalB{vDyvBi}BkkD{M}yDhuCycDbhG~hAbpGqCryFwfAncE{|Bh}DioFbgBesGLa}GewByjGuyHqeI}zAwsCml@wy@}KihCbgBw}DlrGmoIzbAkhCbz@s{H|zA}|DuIs`A_W{_AwLa_Aj%5Cc_BbiCwpCbm@aoAsNg|D}oBsjDueDoaCcqDi~@{gIapEyaC_fCu~@}lDmt@ucAwOkt@dCcb@d[u`BnE_|@kLqwBagAohGvLcvEpXalAbm@eeAn_Ai~@jaAee@xfDghAdwCkd@bUeXlGw|@pSus@ts@ojAtsAeeA~pA_l@h~@q}@ngAw{Jf{@_fCoe@wwG|SoqCv%5Cc_Axg@y_Avy@eu@|rAo]ruAn@zr@nZnm@rc@jfArVpuApCpeAuIjpCsc@hi@o@pzAjGlg@{Enj@w%5CnMsc@`Eyb@pPw%5CzcFymFreBm{Crs@szCpHkt@xiBavBlJyRgN_vBfVmt@fpAs`A|dCui@thC`Rb|Bdx@b_BxiAfzBxiCvaAde@tkB|KjfBe[xnBucAf_Eu}Cz{F~N`mFwyAt`K}`Hr{@s`Bl_@iuBtf@eeBj~Bk~@fuAwyAvd@sSvdI?h^iDfVeXr`A}u@|_CcoApp@ao@zgAwyAnbAeoBrp@qzBlR{yB?kuEiLmdAwy@qzAkLuv@eCylAkLeeAwTwy@o]ui@eCcr@rmBmt@nb@y_@hLmg@tkJe`IhsAao@xiB{oB|zAqdCze@knBuLsqFi^smCoz@q}@`pEah_@drBelE~oDumCdvFcb@pXmJ~eB_OfVwLrx@zRt`BdhAvt@zRtn@cExo@{U|gCu`Bx_@eh@zgAqwC`|@yyAjWyo@tQyyB}XmqBqlDsrKss@usA}jA_|@gAs`AnHoz@~Sow@t^}x@vd@{o@znDeoC|_C{lCrk@k~@j%5CkW|x@uV~p@}K|m@iQnr@mg@jl@qm@~p@sf@xw@eXr`A?|mAxRnz@dHhv@cRjaAwy@nu@ydAswfApk`Csi[dzRu|Afuf@yxy@bxb@jsC|oB~xIiAd{PcoAt`Bao@l~Lw_PzfEavDva@`b@d`@jGp`@mMjfBsmA`aBy_@|SaBfp@ui@x_@acEvWi{@ztAcHxlA`b@hfAfKnbA{oAg{@_fBzMsp@xt@wOtv@WvfBsSbe@mt@rSojAxaBwpDr^oj@jq@qPlw@eKd@a_@sKeh@xOwi@|CyRt^mt@xb@__@xOdh@tIvi@r[|[lg@zRlo@fN|jByvClmGyl@z}OtV~zLpwCzz@vfAdxGrcArxAr}AldAm~C~Neu@pm@?wDl~Cjq@f[vpCoz@~eCsFldJ_iAr_EoMprAmWnwAufAhsAeHdwCxOlqBf{@}[j{BfuBbr@n|CpdDjkBduAreB|h@l~C|e@nqCkGl_A{|AblBs{IiAa|@g}Brc@cr@sFoMwfAlZ{UxxDikBltAjt@hv@_%5C`ZufAc@alAe`@ghAgoDsdFhpBi^vnBlt@j~A`iBv~@|bCllA}eApCmqBsNu`C`R_sB~cAinA`lAiQbhGtcAbj@fAnb@|Hf`BltAzUxBnUuY~p@yl@lZui@zMgx@t^yo@llAkTnbA`Bxl@|HnoAp`@`_AtIpu@?be@xRh^jxCti@lJhv@qPhv@mJ|kF?rs@oM`R{b@|H}h@tY{b@j}EmdBnz@q}@~SoaCg^ibEf^spA~zB{bAjmFdbCpjA?~hAmtAhYufAzMeeA|]mt@dhAkTb_AtVvkCtpBngAp`@lE}rAt^a_Apm@{Rbr@tf@nUduAgKboAtAvfAtcA`_Ati@kq@rmBblBliBbrAtxBts@teCnM??jpD`Rr}Bjd@ryFdrB~~FtsAlkDjnBb}@xOt}BaR~dFgxA|lC{RbhGfKpnGfk@~aFnzAjcCtzCzEb_CwLtzC~Nt`Ct`B|u@peArFz]zUnEpm@o@~hAtYtfAd}@nj@|eAbb@xt@fk@jd@ldBz]l~B~k@`lBnoAxl@vjFwfAdwBgNnr@r`Ati@ziCxfBrc@rlF_Yz|AvLh{AlW`b@fNpgCxyAlRzHpUbEdeBtIhn@vL`g@v%5CmxiCyn`A?qC???giF|KufAvy@{yBjL_|@{Mi~@sc@us@_pDqwC_iAcr@uVy|@sFoz@jL_y@hf@}x@lb@wfA~CqmAsC}bAzEsf@tv@g[|u@iAxo@uLfc@q}@?mg@_Oka@aRo]gF}X}@}HKaoAhArFkD}fFbR{|B|p@{|AlyA_l@bcFuY|uAka@b_BghBrc@u`BW}vFpXkGfs@gx@zj@_|@o@mWxgA}Hlo@nM~bBtsArc@}eAp`@kG`b@`R~h@vLt}C~^ff@nM|Pzo@kOtv@}@fn@h{@bRzu@_Ld`@q`@jYwi@`b@ui@jgGy`Fbe@ogAmBu`CwW}bBpSupArbCalAx~C_|@fgDoZxnC|e@|uAziCreAy`Ehv@wiAnfFmw@rvFoqBtpCuYfp@fK~pArs@l_ApPl|@q@fkIghAhkAia@heDogBrx@vyAdbCg{@zjIkoGpgBss@pzBka@`vCeKx~BblB}~dC`sf@mkq@llgAoa_A|vXcbu@ria@colAceIskq@ha@uf_@~}[jlB_al@xtWcsVvkCpm@t{@ss@tv@ikAhbEmdAbrAcoAbb@eeB_l@_fBnr@avBjpE_vBz~D_OW||DbbAqSpX}e@dHwi@tQcXjq@_L~VjDrSbHlg@o@`g@`EvWtVlWbH|e@{e@~Feu@sx@ikBzEwv@ha@oP|gBsFr^wLxOyl@oEeh@yJmg@n@om@tv@_cCp}@ee@tkAyEpbBsc@eXcUk%5Ceh@uYkTbgBwLn{DlJz~Dbb@zoBzr@|Xw`CWe_DxRodC~uAsp@c@glFdKuv@`Zin@bj@oj@wq@ikBzr@qgBprAknBnj@{|B`o@mdAhkBg{@rrBq@ldArjBrf@upAbRw|@gKwYxt@nJv%5Cf^xRx_@lWvLzmH?rfPucAnwAVp}Anw@zJlJp[vOsIjd@eXzb@cMnMn]z|ArhAdKnnDgk@p[ze@xd@nwA|Xz|AgFnz@wd@zoAph@`|@zwAvOldBcr@ld@`yB~^b_Abb@tYr`B}Xhs@oz@ph@_y@nyCeu@ztBusBbu@oZrhAyRnMmt@_WgbDfpAyOd_DhQtpBeh@mw@acEaw@{r@atAi~@}bAeeAeCwfAlo@mJjuDpPt~@cExJxl@r[fk@dh@jTjq@_YzHmg@{Hm~Dfs@mt@zdBbEbbA|u@kq@z_Bj~Atv@jd@umDwLgiF{u@}rBayAsc@}h@n@qP~x@cb@lw@q[zb@wTvOsmAmg@lg@s`BlyAogB`gAi{@x%5CaBzUxO`RjTdPrFvTaO|h@mw@vT}Kfs@xE~s@~[dbJnMviA_%5Cnz@aEb_Ahq@r{@jaAxo@|e@peAcEp}@{e@|Pi{@y|@q`ArSmWhIyOrNgk@~k@sVpeAuv@f`Aa_@r[xl@p`@be@hkAy|@v{BgrCfkIycE`lAmqAbqDheCrxA~k@jsBha@n_Bfk@bgAtI~`A__@~VghAyWc_AkG}u@fhAgk@drA`vCbXtVz|AmJrVq]sFeh@c@wl@{MghApXmg@ncFeh@bUjTao@tvAjThNxEn@fCbElMzUfmAa|@rk@eXph@qChcAhAj~AoMphA}e@lW}u@}p@q}@nm@ui@~[fk@tf@pSdp@o@zw@sS{b@a_Asp@y_A}`@wy@tI{o@~x@mJ`nC|_BdmAzU?_i@sk@cu@ff@wYrhAaR|z@e[d`A{vCvYwfBkYin@sAsf@bu@owAreAowAzm@}e@j%5Cy_@bZi~@zm@{b@nwApm@oiDp~FdwCy_@fuAy_AzgAcoAdrBylAr[du@lo@xR`_A{E~|AtA{~cAyzhB{oc@hyYiq}@hkSabdBvtaBpFuA??`cC{m@bUcElWW`ZkDd}@sf@nr@_y@lkDyjGrhBmaCts@a_@hq@{Hjd@kTp`@mnC`l@wy@`{DswDf{@kd@jzEaB|zBkd@`lAqzA|wB}vEnmHsaGiIoqDk%5CyfB{EspAx%5Ca_Az{NqrJ~pAqmAx|@uf@pmAmZnbAmd@r[a_A~[{b@p}@~x@f{@jqAzUlg@pm@rFjl@iDji@_Orc@mWmfC}bBdPkuDf`Bo~DliBi{Bb|Bow@raOotBy_@zoAkTdXwa@bU?xl@pfEzEnkFk{ArgD{|CmB}yDn_BdeAnoBb|Bn|Ajt@nrAskIxiBoMh`CzR`nBi{AvG{lAua@uv@cj@ss@mOghAd`@}uA~x@{b@|u@xRxWjnA`Zrf@n|Bd_BfxAnm@wTh~@c_BzyBdeAhDfx@cHhn@cRne@mZbj@kt@lRaiBvYsp@vqAw|@jlH{vC~mBucBbiD{fE~eB}rAjy@}XtpBcb@~k@mZlWcb@ne@q}AnUkd@xfCm~Bze@in@~zBi_G~pAqzAvgPm|IjsBqp@vsCeXxzFpCztBsS|bBkdAfrCjt@pdEdHdyDkTzoBeh@l|@n]|iDhn@laClJax|@j~@ekh@brl@yreBr~j@_ssAzkwApdCgjDjnAodCnz@yfC~[ciDep@yeO`JkhD~^szCvy@_sCd_CokEjzEgnPzjA{lC|nEgyF|[e_D__@clBvhC_cEuNo`GnmAuqG_nLewBzEyyAv}@gxD??h@}B{A~CheRqhRhyHojZzqVy~TubUrmT}yGt{Z_aU~~R~gbA_z|@~mcAv`bArnf@ikSbhQnmj@|eq@xx{@dLJeLK}g@rNm|@nMicAtf@or@bu@}Kx|@hY|e@bm@|KvxBiDfs@sShv@uf@bu@mZnr@xRxdAdeArp@~[dp@zEhcAVrjC_OxiBuv@xvD{vDnj@xyBr}ArmAhxBpSv{B{r@rcAvfApjAcEhnAoz@~mAqzAhsB|eAvxCoz@`fC}_Cr{@aiCvcCzbAtpBjGdwTccF|Pex@bj@in@tq@g^rh@oJzMuLdeA}_Bxb@sVdP|HlJzU`RdKj~AtVn|Adx@xnDpgCts@q`@bjAmJtmDhAe`~@ccWihC`fCmiB~{@ipBpPqcHjG{yKtv@{iDlaAkfAeHaoAq`@olBdKcqDxiBerApzAqwBvwF}p@bu@bz@pzAlg@|oB{Mb_B_bApX{b~D{czClaCdXtzD`yAfp@zEhq@cEfp@oMb_Bao@vtHapEhfAfuB~qF~eAsN`lBvqAwy@|PwcC~c@_cCrjC_|@bgA{EfrCg^brAmGzo@tV~A|u@e[nz@al@jd@?|h@~~F??}h@_vAgNua@us@fNehA`_AalAztAq]jaAvL|h@wLfNusBp@wcBbMqjBjg@k~AvnAg{@dp@fNtqAtl@??hCjAxqAz_A~c@h~@kLr`Bcb@nZ{gBiQaRiQwDwi@lBowArKq}@p[{UlHkA??vSgDzP}KtN}|BrNa_Az]g[`~CmZr`A|Hpu@`_A|e@?lJ_sCxb@mkDxaAqwC~eBusA?ti@zwAkd@be@dh@vTxlAph@ldAndBnw@nHa|@iLc_B|`@kq@hkBiDmBhD~`@|Hv_@tYld@vLfn@w%5C`t@knAvd@gkA~k@ow@llA{Ufp@o]vy@s`A~hAa|@f`BwOjTpPjt@tfAtI`RrSzUbzIzElsDuY`vCg{@jnB{|A';
        var polyline = L.Polyline.fromEncoded(encoded).addTo(map);

        var polygon = L.Polygon.fromEncoded(encoded, {
            weight: 2,
            color: 'red',
            fillColor: 'transparent'
        }).addTo(map);



        map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this part from your script:

```
var polygon = L.Polygon.fromEncoded(encoded, {
    weight: 2,
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: 'transparent'
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Stefan, your suggestion worked. Thank you.